# notifydatasetchanged() is not updating the recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

i am trying to update recyclerview with images from a API using ASYNC task but its not working properly . The problem is with the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method in the `onPostExecute()` of the ASYNC task. i have checked the json response and the result of the `onPostExecute()` the value are correct but the `notifydatasetchanged()` is not updating the adapter with the new data.

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    public MovieUtils utils = new MovieUtils();


    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MovieAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    public ArrayList<String> movieData=new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        //Using a grid layout manager to display the movies in a grid view.
        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        //using the jsonParser to parse the String response and create a new data set.
        // passing the data to the Adapter.
        mAdapter = new MovieAdapter(movieData, getApplicationContext());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        DownloadMovieDetail downloadMovieDetail= new DownloadMovieDetail();
        downloadMovieDetail.execute();

    }

    private class DownloadMovieDetail extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
            ArrayList<String> movieDb = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                movieDb = utils.downloadMovie(responseString);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return movieDb;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> strings) {
            movieData.addAll(strings);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"the movie data"+movieData.toString());
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Movie Adapter:

```
public class MovieAdapter extends       RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public static final String LOG_TAG = MovieAdapter.class.getName();

    public ArrayList<String> dummyData;
    public Context context;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView MovieImageView;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            MovieImageView=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_image);
        }
    }

    //Constructor for the adapter.
    public MovieAdapter(ArrayList<String> data, Context c){
        this.context=c;
        dummyData=data;
    }


    @Override
    public MovieAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.movie_view, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MovieAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(dummyData.toString()).into(holder.MovieImageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return dummyData.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why my comment was deleted?  again first ... obvious reason is that in `onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> strings)`  - `strings` is empty ... second: do you know what `dummyData.toString()` returns? ... why are you feeding the Picasso with such stuff ... it doesn't make sens

Answer (score -1):

Define a setter for dummyData ArrayList in your adapter like this

```
public void setDummyData(ArrayList<String> data){
     this.dummyData = data;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and then onPostExecute() replace

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

with

```
mAdapter.setDummyData(movieData);
```

Answer (score -1):

You did't change the data on the adapter class. Create a setter for the `ArrayList` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
public void setList(ArrayList<String> dummyData){
   this.dummyData = dummyData;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And on `onPostExecute` just call

`adapter.setList(string);`

Comment: guys i have tried your  answer the problem is still there.!

Comment: why are you trying to get the image url from the ArrayList with `dummyData.toString()`?

Comment: *guys i have tried your answer the problem is still there.!* ... because as i wrote problem is not here ... but someones flag this comment without the reasons

Comment: @VassilisPallas it is nothing personal ... just as I wrote the problem is not here ... If his code will not fail in some other place this change(your answer) will not chane anything ... The point is that it is not possible to answer to this question without some logs ... like for example strings.size() in onPostExecute ... second problem is that it may show empty ImageView because .of `Picasso.with(context).load(dummyData.toString()).into(holder.MovieImageView)` .. *i have checked the json onPostExecute() ..notifydatasetchanged() is not updating* is basically is not possible with his code ...

Comment: @VassilisPallas dummyData.toString() is just to log the output and to check if the correct list came from the doInBackgroud().

Comment: i found the problem its with the Picasso.with(context).load(dummyData.toString()).into(holder‌​.MovieImageView) this line .Since i am converting the arraylist into a string the picaso could not load. i have corrected this with converting the Arraylist into a string[] .

Comment: final String[] imagem= dummyData.toArray(new String[dummyData.size()]);
        Picasso.with(context).load(imagem[position]).into(holder.MovieImageView);

Comment: lol .... why not just `Picasso.with(context).load(dummyData.get(position)).into(holder.Mov‌​ieImageView);` .... you are creating array from arraylist at every getView call - what a waste of resources ... It will take ages till you become a programmer